# JavaFX FXML Align to the left

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'm trying to align the Text to the left but keep the picture in the center. How can I achieve this? (the image can be change, it's just there for reference)

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>


<VBox prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0" alignment="CENTER"  fx:controller="controller.LoginController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" spacing="10">


    <HBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT" spacing="10">
    <Button fx:id="loginBtn" text="Login" onAction="#handleLogin"/>
    <Button fx:id="exitBtn" text="Exit" onAction="#handleExit" />
    </HBox>
    
    <Label  text="STPFX"  />
    <Label text="Payroll Management System"/>
    <ImageView fitHeight="300" fitWidth="300" >
        <image><Image url ="@stp.jpg"  /></image>
    </ImageView>
    
</VBox>
```

Comment: Does this help: [The rule "-fx-text-alignment" doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326525/the-rule-fx-text-alignment-doesnt-work)

Comment: Wrap the Label in a `FlowPan` or both  labels in a `VBox`

Comment: @c0der do you mean ___FlowPane___ ?

Comment: If it worked, please post the solution as an answer, you can accept it with enough reputation and time. You can credit a helpful comment in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should create VBox for the 2 labels with alignment = left and maxWidth.

```
<VBox prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0" alignment="CENTER"  fx:controller="controller.LoginController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" spacing="10">

   <HBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT" spacing="10">
      <Button fx:id="loginBtn" text="Login" onAction="#handleLogin"/>
      <Button fx:id="exitBtn" text="Exit" onAction="#handleExit" />
   </HBox>

   <VBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308">
      <Label  text="STPFX"  />
      <Label text="Payroll Management System"/>
   </VBox>

   <ImageView fitHeight="300" fitWidth="300" >
      <image><Image url ="@stp.jpg"  /></image>
   </ImageView>

</VBox>
```